# Did anyone understand the ending of "Zodiac"?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, ending, zodiac

I get most of *Zodiac* but it's the ending I don't get. Anyone that can explain what happened in a way I could understand would be great.

At the end (I can't remember their names) the guy who's obsessed with the zodiac case walks into a shop and finds the alleged zodiac. But why didn't they arrest him? Was it lack of evidence? Or what?

And on top of that what does it mean showing that part at the end? Did it try to convey a message showing that scene?

Answer (score 11):

The evidence acquired by Graysmith that could implicate Allen was merely circumstantial in nature. [Circumstantial evidence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumstantial_evidence) is insufficient to form an entire case or charges against an individual, as they can lead to one or more conclusions. Without additional physical evidence to corroborate a story provided by the circumstantial evidence, nothing can really be done as guilt can't be reasonably assigned.

Graysmith likely wanted Allen to know he believed he was the killer, but given he already lost his job and wife due to trying to uncover the killer to no avail, it's not very likely anyone would have listened to him at the time.

The intent of the scene is to simply show Graysmith still and will likely always believe Allen was the Zodiac killer, but ultimately leaves everything open for the viewer to interpret. Was Allen really guilty, or was Graysmith being driven insane by his obsession with the case?

Comment: [Can Circumstantial Evidence Get You Convicted Of A Serious Crime?](http://www.ronaldcarterlaw.com/can-circumstantial-evidence-get-you-convicted-of-a-serious-crime/)

Answer (score 5):

Complementing [MattD](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/5733/mattd)'s answer, that scene is also there for another reason. Earlier in the movie, Robert Graysmith (the cartoonist obsessed with finding Zodiac) explains his obsession.

> I need to know who he is. I need to stand there, I need to look him in the eye and I need to know that it's him.

### This scene is what finally gives him closure.

It is what finally lets him lay off the case, so he can finish his book and close this chapter in his life. After this, he can finally return to his family, and move on with his life.

Comment: Wow! Can't agree more :D Most possible reason would be this as Graysmith doesn't have the intention of arresting or exposing Zodiac as much as Dave,the cop wants.So,the last scene most probably represent that Graysmith wants to know it's him.Also before that particular scene,Graysmith never had a chance to meet Leigh,the alleged suspect.So this explains it all.